# How to achieve deterministic multithreading in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

As we know, threads are non-deterministic as a model of computation. However, in some situations, we would like to take advantage of the performance gain with parallel computing by multithreading, while keeping the execution deterministic at the same time to make it easy for some general demands such as debugging or some specific demands. I know it is possible to achieve deterministic multithreading for a particular task, but I am looking forward to a general and elegant way (that is to say, not require lots of trivial engineering work) to achieve that in C/C++. It does not matter what type of the solution is: it is okay to achieve it by some libraries, by some platforms, by some general methodologies, or by any other ways.

Comment: a multi-threaded code MUST produce the exactly the same output that the serial code, if not it's a problem .... Look at Open MP, Bolt, Boost::thread but a framework will not ensure that you use it in a correct way :)

Comment: _...threads are non-deterministic as a model of computation_ Do you consider this a basic rule?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are tools for C/C++ readily available, but researchers definitely work in this direction. I found a few papers that might be of interest: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/commit/papers/09/asplos073-olszewski.pdf, https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/lee612/publications/ecoop14.pdf and http://www.cs.ust.hk/~charlesz/academic/leap.pdf

Comment: @mephi42 Thanks for your comments. I know there are some work in this direction (this is also one of the reason I think my question may get some solutions) and I also read some of them, however just like you, I am not sure whether there are tools readily available. Anyway, thank you all the same.

Comment: @Arno Threads are non-deterministic as model of computation, but fundamentally it does not contradict with that we could achieve deterministic multithreading by adding some constraints during threads' execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want determinism for debugging you can try to use [CHESS tool](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/) from Microsoft Research:

> CHESS is a tool for finding and reproducing Heisenbugs in concurrent
>   programs. CHESS repeatedly runs a concurrent test ensuring that every
>   run takes a different interleaving. If an interleaving results in an
>   error, CHESS can reproduce the interleaving for improved debugging.
>   CHESS is available for both managed and native programs.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a really powerful tool.

Comment: I know CHESS before asking this question, however I wish the solution is general, not restricts in debugging. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Although I wish more general solutions, It seems that there are no additional answers. I thought your answer is the one which is the closest to what I would like, so I choose your answer as my accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

You achieve deterministic multi-threading in the same way you have mutable constants - you don't.

Instead you use various forms of synchronisation (including things like mutexes, semaphores, conditional variables, signals, etc) to ensure you get deterministic results (where needed) from non-deterministic code. Of course the more synchronisation you use the less parallelism you get from the code; so you only want the minimum synchronisation necessary.

How to do this depends on the exact algorithm - there is no "silver bullet" that is the best way of doing synchronisation that works for all of the wildly different problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that there's no "silver bullet" which is the best way of achieving deterministic multithreading for wildly problems, however, what I want is some solution(s) which may not be the best, but is not bad to some degree and could achieve deterministic multithreading easily for general tasks, so that I could save some time on dealing with different tasks (no longer need to figure out various solutions for different tasks). Could you provide me with more ideas on that? :)

Comment: Being a pedant here - you _can_ have deterministic multi-threading. For example if you're the one scheduling the threads manually you can create a model where you know the exact order of operations and they're still parallelized. It's just not very practical in real life.